# IE and Chrome caches 'no-cache' images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, google-chrome, amazon-s3, browser-cache

Hi I'm using fragment caching extensively in my rails application. I've cached fragments which have user images in them. So when a user changes his/her avatar(image), a lot of fragments have to be expired. To solve this, I've made some settings so that a user's avatar URL is always constant ( "/avatars/:user_id/thumbs" ).

Im using amazon s3 for storage and the expires header for the images is "no-cache".
Sample image URL : https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/avatars/388/thumbs

In IE and Chrome, Im facing a peculiar problem. When a user changes his avatar, it is not reflected immiediately on client side. It takes 2-3 page refresh for the image to change. Has anyone faced similar issues before?

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this the wrong way in my opinion. Expire the fragment as you're doing but allow rails' cache busting timestamps to force the browser to download new images.

e.g. s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/avatars/388/thumbs/filename.jpg?**1230601161**